# Braintree, skip showing Dropin and straight select PayPal

Tags: swift, paypal, braintree

Currently, when I try to pay with paypal, it will show this DropIn first:

[image]

But my client want to straight access to PayPal without showing this DropIn.

This is the code to show dropIn:

```
fileprivate  func showDropIn(clientTokenOrTokenizationKey: String) {
        let request =  BTDropInRequest()
        request.cardDisabled = false
        let dropIn = BTDropInController(authorization: clientTokenOrTokenizationKey, request: request)
        { (controller, result, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
               //print("ERROR")
            } else if (result?.isCancelled == true) {
               //print("CANCELLED")
            } else if let result = result {
               print(
                    "paymentOptionType: ", result.paymentOptionType,
                    "paymentMethod: ", result.paymentMethod as Any,
                    "paymentIcon: ", result.paymentIcon,
                    "paymentDescription: ", result.paymentDescription,
                    "paymentMethod: ", result.paymentMethod?.nonce as Any
                )
                self.postNonceToServer(paymentMethodNonce: result.paymentMethod!.nonce )
            }
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        self.present(dropIn!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

If you are looking to display only the PayPal button it pay be easier to make a standalone PayPal button within your Braintree integration as this will give you more control over your UI.

Having said that, you can use `request.cardDisabled = true` to disable the credit card option within your Drop-in.

Answer (score 0):

To only show PayPal as payment option, use the parameter `paymentOptionPriority` :

```
paymentOptionPriority:['paypal']
```

Also have a look at the [drop-in documentation on github](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web-drop-in/docs/current/module-braintree-web-drop-in.html#.create), where you can find *paymentOptionPriority* listed as an optional property of the *options* object:

> Use this option to indicate the order in which enabled payment options
>   should appear when multiple payment options are enabled. By default,
>   payment options will appear in this order: ['card', 'paypal',
>   'paypalCredit', 'venmo', 'applePay', 'googlePay']. **Payment options
>   omitted from this array will not be offered to the customer**.

(Actually I found no information about *paymentOptionPriority* on developers.braintreepayments.com)